# DataTable is not accepting the height I give it in Shiny. This leeds to overlaps

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to use a `DT::dataTableOutput` to display some information about my dataset and then a few input rows and buttons to give the user the chance to interact with my app. However the `height` attribute seems to lead to strange behaviour:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("dtout", height = "300px"),
      fluidRow(
        actionButton("btn1","Btn1"),
        actionButton("btn2","Btn2"),
        actionButton("btn3","Btn3"),
        actionButton("btn4","Btn4"),
        actionButton("btn5","Btn5"),
        actionButton("btn6","Btn6"),
        actionButton("btn7","Btn7"),
        actionButton("btn8","Btn8"),
        actionButton("btn9","Btn9"),
      )
      
      
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel()
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dtout <- DT::renderDT(iris)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The result is not looking good:

[image: DataTable overlaps with other UI if height is used]

What can you propose to better control the height?

Answer (score 0):

In `fluidRow` you have to use `column`:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("dtout", height = "300px"),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          12,
          actionButton("btn1","Btn1"),
          actionButton("btn2","Btn2"),
          actionButton("btn3","Btn3"),
          actionButton("btn4","Btn4"),
          actionButton("btn5","Btn5"),
          actionButton("btn6","Btn6"),
          actionButton("btn7","Btn7"),
          actionButton("btn8","Btn8"),
          actionButton("btn9","Btn9")
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel()
  )
)
```

Comment: This way the height attribute has no effect. But OK, I guess I will just use the `options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 5)` parameter in `DT::renderDT` in order to limit the height of the datatable.

Comment: @Noskario Ah indeed, you're right. Weird.